# SPI timeout in Linux and C

Tags: c, linux, spi

I'm trying to implement a timeout for some hardware transmissions, to add security to a big project. I already implemented timeout using `select` for UART transmission, but I don't know how to add a timeout in a SPI transmission.

This is my reading code:

```
int spi_read(int fd, char command, char* buffer, int size, int timeout)
{
    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer[2];
    int status;

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    memset(xfer, 0, sizeof(xfer));

    xfer[0].tx_buf = (unsigned int)(&command);
    xfer[0].len = 1;

    xfer[1].rx_buf = (unsigned int)buffer;
    xfer[1].len = size;

    status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(2), xfer);
    if(status < 0)
        return NOERROR;
    else
        return EHWFAULT1;
}
```

It sends a byte sized command and receives a response of certain size (in half duplex mode). How can I implement a timeout in the response? Can it be implemented using `select`? Should I separe both transactions and use `select` or better use an alarm?

Then, I have the same question for a full duplex mode, which is implemented too using ioctl. Can you give me any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In hardware the SPI master does not 'wait' for a response.  By definition, the SPI master provides the clock cycles and the slave must reply.  The concept of waiting for a response doesn't apply to the SPI bus. (I'm assuming you're operating the SPI master)

(deeper in the protocol, the SPI might poll the hardware to see if it's done/ready; but the SPI bus itself is getting an immediate answer every time).

To clarify: the SPI clocks in whatever is on the SPI MISO pin.  Whatever level is on the MISO pin is the reply, even if the slave is not explicitly driving a level.  The only way to detect a non responsive slave is to pullup/pulldown the MISO in a way that can not be interpreted as a valid message.

[image: Typical SPI protocol]

Comment: So SPI is not blocking?

Comment: SPI will not block indefinitely.  It is possible that you may have a very long exchange (or slow bit rate) that caused a transfer to take longer than you want to wait, but as the SPI master you would know your transfer rate and data length beforehand; there would be no surprises in delay.  I used an SPI flash memory chip that you *could* read the whole thing with one SPI command, but I've never seen an SPI protocol where the read length could possibly depend on the data itself.